# fade out an image on iOS

Tags: ios, uiimage, fade

The code below fades out the current image, but it results in all buttons disappearing for some odd reason.

```
self.imageThree = [UIImage imageNamed:@"newscreensh.png"];
self.imageTwo = [UIImage imageNamed:@""];

UIImage * toImage = ([self.imageView.image isEqual:self.imageThree]) ? self.imageTwo : self.imageThree;

[UIView transitionWithView:self.imageView
                  duration:0.8f
                   options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCrossDissolve
                animations:^{
                      self.imageView.image = toImage;
               }completion:NULL];
```

When I use this code below, all buttons do not disappear.

```
loader.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@""];
```

However, I need a fade effect to smooth things out. What could possibly be happening to my storyboard buttons?

Comment: I didn't get what you are looking for? Assumption, You are trying to change image for UIImageView with animation, but problem is , while animating image view, all buttons are disappear from view? Am I right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
self.imageThree = [UIImage imageNamed:@"newscreensh.png"];
//self.imageTwo = [UIImage imageNamed:@""];   

UIImage *toImage = self.imageView.image != nil?nil:self.imageThree;
```

Since isEqual will compare whether two image's data have the same number of bytes,and `[UIImage imageNamed:@""]` return nil value, so you only need to compare wether imageView's image is nil.return `nil` or `imageThree` to achieve fade out animation.

```
[UIView transitionWithView:self.imageView
                  duration:0.8f
                   options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCrossDissolve
                animations:^{
                      self.imageView.image = toImage;
               }completion:NULL];

loader.image = nil; //you don't have to use [UIImage imageNamed:@""] to remove imageView's image.
```

Answer (score 0):

To fade an image, you can change its alpha value like this:

```
[self.imageTwo setAlpha:0.5];
```

Here if alphaValue is 0, image would be completely transparent. Alpha values ranges between 0 & 1. Let me know if this is not what you need.